# Como configurar o mySQL e o apache manualmente?

Tags: mysql, apache

Eu usava o xamp mas sempre dava alguns problemas de porta, então baixei e configurei o apache e o PHP manualmente, só que agora não sei como configurar o workbench e integrar ele com o apache

Comment: Isso é Windows? Linux/Unix? Mac OS? E como assim "integrar com o Apache"?

Comment: Windows, por exemplo quando eu baixo o xampp já vem tudo pronto pra mim, e eu consigo usar o mysql e o apache com o phpmyadin que já vem tudo pronto, mas eu queria aprender a configurar manualmente e não achei nada, eu fiz o download do apache do mysql e do phpmyadmin sem o xampp, o apache eu consegui configurar certinho, agora o phpmyadmin e o mysql eu não to conseguindo..

Comment: Eu acho que vc consegue resolver essas dúvidas aqui: [Documentação do phpMyAdmin](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/pt_BR/latest/) ;)

Comment: Só para deixar claro, uma vez que o StackOverflow só mostra os votos de fechamento que foram maioria. Um voto foi por não ser um problema de programação, 3 votos foram por ser ampla demais e o meu voto foi por não ser clara o bastante. Votei assim porque não entendo o que você quer dizer por "integrar ele com o apache".